# Div mouse click to display not working

Tags: html, css

I want to hide `div` until user clicks it then it should be displayed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="cTsdiv"><a href="/{{ i.couponStoreURL }}/#{{ i.id }}">
<span id="couponCode" style="">{{ i.couponCode }}</span></a>
<span class="cTs">Click to see the code</span></div><br><br>
```

**CSS**

```
.cTsdiv {
    height:50px;
    width: 175px;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px dashed;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    background:#EE4000;
    color:white;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

.cTs {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height:30px;
    width: 185px;
    line-height:4em;
    background: black;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.1s;
}

.cTsdiv:hover .cTs {
    opacity:1;
    color:white;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.cTsdiv a {
    font-color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: What is the strange code within your `html`?

Comment: Please ignore that.. Its django template code.

Comment: Where is Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried in order to implement the hiding/showing behavior.

Comment: I have.. posted the CSS i have tried so far.

Comment: You need Javascript or JQuery to hide or show the content.  Css doesn't really do that on it's own.

Comment: The CSS you have posted doesn't have anything to do with the actual behavior you are trying to accomplish. You either need javascript to show/hide the div, or more complex CSS/HTML (basically the "checkbox hack") which you can google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your CSS/HTML, you need some Javascript involved.

```
$('.cTs').on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", 0).delay(100).queue(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

The delay/queue are there to make the script wait till your animation is finished before the `span` is hidden. There's a proper way to do this, but this will do for now.

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/3EMv2/

Comment: Tried but nothing happening.couponCode is visible and when i see the source their is transparent layer of `span class="cTs"`  is shown

Comment: Make sure your CSS and HTML matches the one in the fiddle. It is required for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

one solution to your question may be like this

```
.cTsdiv:hover .cTs {
opacity:1;
color:white;
display:none;
}
.cTsdiv:active .cTs {
opacity:1;
color:white;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cTsdiv a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.cTs').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
});
```

also I have edited some of your css

[jsfiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/M6JKn/2/)